# Parse/rewrite Sparql Query before using in Sansa Application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sparql

I have the below Sparql Query. I want to rewrite it using scala, to further use it in sansa-spark Application.
In the query, I want to eliminate all lines starting with "BIND" and replace all the variables in select part(?doc lita:doi ?doi) with only the variables used in WHERE clause (?d ?doi).

```
SELECT 
{
    ?doc lita:doi ?doi .
}
WHERE 
{
    ?d a dm:Document .
    ?d prism:doi ?doi .
    BIND(STRAFTER(str(?d), "#") as ?docid) .
    BIND(URI(CONCAT(\"http://lit-search-api/node/doc#\", ?docid)) as ?doc) .
    BIND(STRAFTER(str(?ds), "#") as ?secid) .
    BIND(URI(CONCAT(\"http://lit-search-api/node/docsec#\", ?secid)) as ?docsec) .
}
```

Final query should look like below

```
    SELECT 
{
    ?d ?doi .
}
WHERE 
{
    ?d a dm:Document .
    ?d prism:doi ?doi .
}
```

I reached 70% of the solution with the below code-

```
   def parser(query:String) = {

    var Input_query=query
    var Replaced_query=Input_query.replace("CONSTRUCT", "SELECT")
    /*println("replaced string is "+Replaced_query)*/

    val Bind_Index = Replaced_query.indexOf("BIND")
    val No_Bind_Query = Replaced_query.substring(0,Bind_Index) + "}"
    println("-----------------------------------------------------")
    println(No_Bind_Query)
  }
```

But, I'm still stuck with, how to replace the variables,(or column names what ever one calls it) in the SELECT{} part(?doc lita:doi ?doi .) with only the variables used in the WHERE{} clause part(?d ?doi .).

So, now my query looks like-

```
    SELECT 
{
    ?doc lita:doi ?doi .
}
WHERE 
{
    ?d a dm:Document .
    ?d prism:doi ?doi .
}
```

But, I want it to be like-

```
    SELECT 
{
    ?d ?doi .
}
WHERE 
{
    ?d a dm:Document .
    ?d prism:doi ?doi .
}
```

Comment: you should use a proper SPARQL parser like it's contained in Apache Jena or RDF4J. then it's pretty straightforward to extract the triple patterns and omit the `BIND` clauses.

Comment: @UninformedUser , I have huge data to process, hence using sansa stack with spark to process the data, but the challenge is sansa 0.7.1 is not able to execute BIND operations, hence I need to remove it from the query and write e custom code.

Comment: I understand the problem, but my comment was just to use a proper SPARQL parser like in Apache Jena or RDF4J  to **parse and modify** the query, not to execute the query.

Comment: Ohk. @UninformedUser ,Thats a usefull sugession. In that case can I get a similar SQL statement by parsing the SPARQL with the jena or similar library ?

Comment: No, I just meant to transform the SPARQL query. I mean, this is what you're trying to achieve, or not? But instead of doing weird error prone string hacks, you should use a SPARQL parser to get a query object and work in this query structure.